# In-app updates not working. Unable to bind the service error

Tags: android, in-app-update

I am trying to setup the in-app updates dialog in Android but it's not working from the example provided in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

I have tried the examples available in the docs which ask you to do this.

```
appUpdateManager
    .getAppUpdateInfo()
    .addOnSuccessListener(
        new OnSuccessListener<AppUpdateInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo) {
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                    // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            IMMEDIATE,
                            MainActivity.this,
                            MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: onResume" + e.getMessage() );
        }
    });
```

Expected a result that tells gives me some option where it tells me that an updates is actually available. But it directly gives me the error unable to bind to the service.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or a real device. I noticed this behaviour when running on emulator. Try using a real device

Comment: I was having this problem and solved it testing in a real device. Didn't manage to make it work on my AVD.

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be an issue with Google Play Core library with Android Virtual Devices. please use the **Real Device**

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the google play store application, and I am getting the same error after this every time I am opening the app on which I am performing this In-App update testing. A very weird implementation has been provided by Google.